# Prove that TM does not decide this language

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata

So my problem is how can I show that this TM does not decides this language.

$$L = \{a^nb^nc^n\  |\  n \geq 0\} $$

[image: sketch of TM]

It might be a basic problem and seem silly to you but still I do not know how to prove that this TM does not halt for any input

Comment: Methodically see what happens for strings abc, aabbcc, aaabbbccc, first. Chances are you will find some string that is not accepted. Hint: last state transitions are not correct/incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to provide a counter example, i.e.

- some $w \in L$ that $M$ does not accept, or
- some $w \not\in L$ that $M$ accepts.

There are two ways to find such.

1. Understand how $M$ works and use this to find such $w$ directly.
2. Try *all* strings in some order, e.g. lexicographically, until you find such $w$.

Note that if $L \subseteq L(M)$ or $L(M) \subseteq L$, only *one* of the two types of counterexamples exist.